# number comparison in IBM Watson Assistant

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I am trying to build a BMI calculator inside Watson but it seems like Watson is not supporting number comparison when you use the "Multiple conditioned responses".

```
<? ($weight /  ($height * $height) ) < 18.5  ?>
```

This code will throw an error:

```
SpelParseException when evaluating dialog node ID [response_8_1624288200413]. Condition [<? ($weight / ($height * $height) ) < 18.5 ?>] could not be parsed. Check the syntax of the expression. SpEL syntax error: Expression [<? ($weight / ($height * $height) ) < 18.5 ?>] converted to [<? (context['weight'] / (context['height'] * context['height']) ) < 18.5 ?>] at position 0: EL1070E: Problem parsing left operand
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example works for me. I can also confirm that [IBM Watson Assistant can compare numbers and has other support for math expressions and number processing](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-methods#dialog-methods-numbers).

This is my response text:

```
This is: <? ($weight / ($height*$height)) < 18.5 ?>
```

I set values for **weight** and **height** in **Manage Context** in the "Try it". Depending on the values, it returns either

> This is: true

or

> This is: false

Have you set any values during your tests?

Comment: Sorry I have this problem under "Multiple conditioned responses". I tried to use this as a condition but it failed

Comment: Could you first assign the result to a variable, then use that variable as condition?

Comment: I already found the reason: You don't need <? ?> in "Multiple conditioned responses". Thank you for helping me!